# getTransactionByHash function is not available in the go-ethereum package

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

In have downloaded go-ethereum package and made the private network. I am able to make changes in the code as per my requirement and it is also working fine. However, ethereum_js.go file has the following lines

```
    var getTransaction = new Method({
    name: 'getTransaction',
    call: 'eth_getTransactionByHash',
    params: 1,
    outputFormatter: formatters.outputTransactionFormatter
    });
```

Above says whenever we use getTransaction, it call eth_getTransactionByHash.

But there is no function avaialable with name getTransactionByHash.

Also the following line is not clear

```
         outputFormatter: formatters.outputTransactionFormatter
```

Comment: Here's the docs for go-etheruem RPC if that helps: https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-eth-module#eth_gettransactionbyhash

Comment: I am not able to find the function

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? There is certainly a `getTransactionByHash()` function in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full example of using the `TransactionByHash` method from the go-ethereum client package.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

func main() {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://mainnet.infura.io")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    txHash := common.HexToHash("0x5d49fcaa394c97ec8a9c3e7bd9e8388d420fb050a52083ca52ff24b3b65bc9c2")
    tx, isPending, err := client.TransactionByHash(context.Background(), txHash)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(tx.Hash().Hex())     // 0x5d49fcaa394c97ec8a9c3e7bd9e8388d420fb050a52083ca52ff24b3b65bc9c2
    fmt.Println(tx.Value().String()) // 10000000000000000 (in wei)
    fmt.Println(isPending)           // false
}
```

Check out the [Ethereum Development with Go](https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-development-with-go-book) guide book for more examples.